# I am tasked with creating a Java application that used 2 synchronized threads to calculate monthly interest and update the account balance

Tags: java, multithreading

This is the parameters for reference to the code.
Create a class AccountSavings. The class has two instance variables: a double variable to keep annual interest rate and a double variable to keep savings balance. The annual interest rate is 5.3 and savings balance is $100.
• Create a method to calculate monthly interest. 
• Create a method to run two threads. Use anonymous classes to create these threads. The first thread calls the monthly interest calculation method 12 times, and then displays the savings balance (the balance in 12th month). After that, this thread sleeps 5 seconds. The second thread calls the monthly interest calculation method 12 times, and then displays the savings balance (the balance in 12th month). Before the main thread ends, these two threads must be completed. 
• Add your main method into the same class and test your threads. After these two threads are executed, the savings balance must remain same

I am getting an error when calling monthlyInterest method inside my runThread method.
non-static method monthlyInterest() cannot be referenced from a static context
and I cant seem to figure out how to fix the issue.

...

```
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

class AccountSavings {

double annualInterest=5.3;
double savings=100.00;



public void monthlyInterest(){
double monthlyRate;
monthlyRate = annualInterest/12;
double balance = 0;
balance+=savings*monthlyRate;
}

public synchronized static void runThread(){

    Thread t1;
    t1 = new Thread(){
        AccountSavings accountSavings= new AccountSavings();
        @Override
        public void run(){
            for(int i=1;i<13;i++){
                System.out.println("Balance after " + i + "month: " + monthlyInterest());
            }
            try{sleep(5000);}
            catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    };
Thread t2= new Thread(){

AccountSavings accountSavings=new AccountSavings();
@Override
public void run(){

    for(int i=1;i<13;i++){
    System.out.println("Balance after " + i + " month: " + monthlyInterest(balance));
    }
    try{sleep(5000);}
    catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}    
}
};
t1.start();
t2.start();

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    runThread();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

What about calling the method from the AccountSavings object?
accountSavings.montlyInterest()

```
class AccountSavings {

   private double annualInterest = 5.3;
   private double balance = 0;

   public void monthlyInterest() {
      double monthlyRate = annualInterest / 12;
      double savings = 100.00;
      balance += savings * monthlyRate;
   }

   public static void runThread() {

      Thread t1;
      t1 = new Thread() {
         AccountSavings accountSavings = new AccountSavings();
         @Override
         public void run() {
            int i=1;
            for (; i < 13; i++) {
               accountSavings.monthlyInterest();
            }
            System.out.println("Balance Thread 1 after " + (i-1) + " month: " + accountSavings.balance);
            try {
               sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // failed to sleep
            }
         }
      };
      Thread t2 = new Thread() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
            AccountSavings accountSavings = new AccountSavings();
            int i=1;
            for (; i < 13; i++) {
               accountSavings.monthlyInterest();
            }
            System.out.println("Balance Thread 2 after " + (i-1) + " month: " + accountSavings.balance);
            try {
               sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // failed to sleep
            }
         }
      };
      t1.start();
      t2.start();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      runThread();
   }
}
```

1. Balance Thread 1 after 12 month: 530.0000000000001
2. Balance Thread 2 after 12 month: 530.0000000000001

Answer (score 0):

First off, the keyword `synchronized` must go to the method that will be executing the critical section, not the method that will be creating the threads. So in this case, it must go to **monthlyInterest**. Now, you are creating two **AccountSavings**, which are being modified by only one thread, so there is no need to add the `synchronized` keyword, unless you expect to modify it by multiple threads. Also, I would recommend on using the Java 8 lambda syntax to create the threads, which is more simply and easier to read. In the end your code would look something like the one below.

**AccountSavings**

```
public class AccountSavings {

    private double annualInterest;
    private double savings;
    private double balance;

    public synchronized double monthlyInterest() {
        double monthlyRate;
        monthlyRate = annualInterest / 12;
        balance += savings * monthlyRate;
        return balance;
    }

    AccountSavings(double annualInterest, double savings, double balance) {
        this.annualInterest = annualInterest;
        this.savings = savings;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            AccountSavings accountSavings = new AccountSavings(5.3, 100, 0);
            for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
                System.out.println("Balance after " + i + "month: " + accountSavings.monthlyInterest() + " | Thread 1");
            }
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error sleeping");
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            AccountSavings accountSavings = new AccountSavings(5.3, 100, 0);
            for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
                System.out.println("Balance after " + i + "month: " + accountSavings.monthlyInterest() + " | Thread 2");
            }
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error sleeping");
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for that information, after talking to my professor she is specifically asking us to create a method to run the threads and then call that method inside the main method. So my question now is, do i keep the runThread method and call it in main or is there a more effective way to do that than the way i currently have done?

Comment: Calling `runThread` inside your main class is ok. There really aren't many choices. You either do it your way, which is calling a static method or creating a new class. I would say that the static method approach is better for this exercise.